# Excel VBA - Change date filter of a pivottable

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a pivottable on my sheet and I'm trying to add a date filter:

```
Private Sub foo()

Dim MyDate
MyDate = #1/27/1993#
Worksheets("Timeline").PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("EndDateFormatted").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlBetween, Value1:=MyDate, Value2:=MyDate

End Sub
```

How ever this results in an "invalid procedure call or argument" error. What am I doing wrong?

Update:
thx luke_t, now I know that I have to use xlDateBetween.
Now my code looks like:

```
Private Sub foo()
    Dim d As Date
    Dim dd As Date

    d = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
    dd = DateSerial(2016, 1, 2)
    Worksheets("Timeline").PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("EndDateFormatted").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=d, Value2:=dd
End Sub
```

Now it says "the date you entered is not a valid date" (1004).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `xlDateBetween` into the `Type:=` parameter of the `PivotFilters.Add` method.

[Here is a list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193582.aspx) of constant names that can be passed into the type parameter.

Use a string with the `Type:=` parameter. See below.

```
Private Sub foo()
    Dim d As String

    d = "01/01/2016"
    Worksheets("Timeline").PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("EndDateFormatted").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=d, Value2:=d
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed that must be one cause of the problem. But now I have an error 1004 (not valid date). I have updated my question with the new code.

Comment: @ThomasMX - I think you should mark this as answered as it fixed your original problem based on the *"invalid procedure call or argument" error.*.  The date issue is almost a separate question - especially since you changed the original code.

Comment: Got "duplicate" on my other question where i asked for the reason to 1004. So  had to remove the green tick. ..

Comment: @ThomasMX Make your date variable a string: `Dim MyDate as String` and then `MyDate = "27/01/1993"`. Make sure to use the correct date format relating to your local settings / data.

Comment: @ThomasMX - see pnuts comment above if you want to re-open the other question.

Comment: Well, regarding the original question (this one ) we still haven't found the 100% correct code so I think the best is if we leave this one open and leave the other one close. I'll check your suggestions later and will give you feedback ASAP.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: @ThomasMX See amended answer. So this doesn't work for you? Make sure the pivot table does not already contain filters on the dates.